# underline a part of text in Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, stylesheet

is it possible to underline a portion of text in  control.

I did like this in jquery, but no underline is appearing. any sample code examples?

```
<textarea rows = "3" cols = "50" id = "TestName" ></textarea>
```

Jquery

```
 var dvHTML = ''
 dvHTML = '<span style=text-decoration: underline;>' + "Hello world" + '</span>';
$("#TestName").html(dvHTML);
```

Output i'm getting as only Hello world, tags are not getting recognized

Comment: I'm just thinking aloud: I'm not sure you can have html tags in a textarea. A solution that comes to my mind is to have a normal html element and set it to contenteditable = True ( http://html5demos.com/contenteditable ). And when you send your text to the server you get it from the div with jQuery

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea

Comment: No, it is not, because the content model of `textarea` is [`Text`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#text-content). Whenever you see such an _effect_, it mean the `textarea`has been _replaced_ with something else (probably a “normal” element with `contenteditable` attribute set).

Comment: If so, then how does sharepoint people picker control works?, how they have implemented that, it does underlining when it recognizes contact

Comment: You could fake the `<textarea>` by `contenteditable` as: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/9PXtu/6/

Comment: Also, it's worth taking a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438418/css3-how-to-style-the-selected-text-in-textareas-and-inputs-in-chrome) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492856/underlining-text-of-a-textarea).

Comment: Yes, out of two one would work only in chrome, another one says use div as fake textbox

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `contenteditable` div.

```
<div contenteditable="true">I am saying <span>Hello</span></div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/gj7Mq/)**

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that on textarea, You'll need some WYSIWYG if you need style on it.
Or you can fake user by adding div above of the textarea, and hide the textarea it self.

Comment: Thanks, are there any sample example?

Comment: If so, then how does sharepoint people picker control works?, how they have implemented that, it does underlining when it recognizes contact

Comment: @Iqbal Fauzi, how can we create the div about the textarea? Is there such an example somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to underline the specific text you can use:

```
<textarea style="text-decoration:underline;" rows="20" cols="30" id="text">All are Welcome!!</textarea>


$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#text").val($("#text").text());
    $('textarea').keypress(function(e) {
          $(this).css('text-decoration','none');
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/czZWp/6/

Comment: this will underline everything inside the textarea

Comment: I want a specific portion of the line to be underlined,

Answer (score 0):

You can't do with a text area, the solution is to use an editable div.

HTML:

```
<div id="foo">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var dvHTML = '<span style="text-decoration: underline;">Hello world</span>';

$("#foo").html(dvHTML).click(function() {
    this.contentEditable = true;                
});
```

**[THE LIVE DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/79mnE/2/)**

Comment: in this case, if my text size is more then div size then it will come out of the border right?, if i hit enter it wont expand like text area na>

Comment: @LLL You could do some css trick to deal with this, check the demo again i updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Add double inverted commas `"` in `style` tag first and then a semicolon after `divHtml = ''`

This will work -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows = "3" cols = "50" id = "TestName" style="text-decoration: underline;"></textarea>
<script>
var dvHTML = '';
 dvHTML =  "Hello world" ;
$("#TestName").html(dvHTML);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And to let you know the difference, the `HTML` that you enter inside the `textarea` will be its text. It will render it as text. So instead add text decoration as style of text area. And, about your original question - its not possible with `textarea`. See this -

[Rendering HTML inside textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea)